# What is the analogue of C#/.NET InternalVisibleTo attribute in Swift?

Tags: .net, swift, encapsulation

In .NET I can do internal members of the assembly visible (accessible) for another concrete assembly by adding of the attribute `[InternalVisibleTo("AnotherConcreteAssembly")]`.

Has Swift any analog for this encapsulation ability?
If yes, How can I open access to internal members of one module for another?

Comment: You are comparing a framework (.net) to a programming language (Swift). This is not a good comparison.

Comment: The closest available analogue appears to be `@testable`.

Comment: @rmaddy You are right. But in this case, it simplifies question for understanding. For example .NET CLR has protected attribute which is integrated into C# as part of the language but into F# not. It is possible that some .NET language integrates InternalVisibleTo into syntax. .NET is something more than a framework as a library. And I don't know how to ask my question correctly, because politic of encapsulation as a common is a part of the language (maybe it present in Swift (I don't know. I ask)).

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you write your comment as answer, please? And I will mark it as correct because it is true.